# Efficiently enforcing a 1:1 relationship between two rows with foreign key constraints without creating redundant unique indexes

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two PostgreSQL tables designed in the following way:

```sql
create type content_owner as enum (
  'document',
  'task'
);

create table content (
  id serial not null primary key,
  owner content_owner not null,
  owner_document_id int references document(id) deferrable initially deferred,
  owner_task_id int references task(id) deferrable initially deferred,

  -- ...

  constraint collab_content_owner_document
  check (owner_document_id is null or (owner = 'document' and owner_document_id is not null)),

  constraint collab_content_owner_task
  check (owner_task_id is null or (owner = 'task' and owner_task_id is not null))
);

create table document (
  id serial not null primary key,
  content_id int not null references content(id),

  -- ...
);

create table task (
  id serial not null primary key,
  content_id int not null references content(id),

  -- ...
);
```

I want to enforce a 1:1 relationship at the database level for the document<->content relationship and the task<->content relationship.

Adding the following constraints accomplishes that:

```sql
alter table collab_content add foreign key (owner_document_id, id) references document (id, content_id) deferrable initially deferred;
alter table collab_content add foreign key (owner_task_id, id) references task (id, content_id) deferrable initially deferred;

alter table document add foreign key (content_id, id) references collab_content (id, owner_document_id);
alter table task add foreign key (content_id, id) references collab_content (id, owner_task_id);
```

Since I’m saying the ID pair should reference the same ID pair in the other table for both directions. However, this also requires me to create the following indexes:

```sql
alter table document add unique (id, content_id);
alter table task add unique (id, content_id);

alter table collab_content add unique (id, owner_document_id);
alter table collab_content add unique (id, owner_task_id);
```

These indexes feel pretty redundant given that there’s already a primary key on the `id` columns for these tables. It feels like PostgreSQL should be smart enough to be able to use the existing primary key constraint to make sure the foreign key constraints are met. Ideally I wouldn’t create a second, redundant, index on these tables for the purpose of these foreign key constraints.

1. Is there a way for me to avoid creating new unique indexes and instead tell PostgreSQL to only lookup the unique ID when resolving the foreign key?
2. Will PostgreSQL detect that these unique indexes are redundant (because the first column is the primary key) and not materialize a new index on disk for their purpose?
3. Is there a better way to enforce this constraint?

Comment: Just to understand your goals right: You want to enforce that there cannot be a content without a corresponding document or task and there cannot be a task or a document without content, is that right?

Comment: Yes that and I also want to enforce that there is only ever one content for a document (there shouldn’t be two contents that reference the same document or two documents that reference the same content). I also don’t want “swapped” references, so no two documents with (documentID1, contentID1) and (documentID2, contentID2) but contents with (contentID1, documentID2) and (contentID2, documentID1).

Comment: `Is there a better way to enforce this constraint?` Yes: combine the two tables.

Comment: In this case I have two tables that need a “content” object, document and task. Is your suggestion to inline all the “content” fields/references into them? I also have other tables that reference content like “content_mentions”. Should I create task_content_mentions and document_content_mentions too?

Answer (score 0):

Two-way linking like this is a recipe for headaches. I recommend avoiding reference cycles if you can. In your case, the simplest way to store this information is to relax the constraint that there cannot be a `content` without a `document` or a `task`. Ask yourself, how might such a situation occur, how else could it be avoided, and what damage might it cause if it happens?

If we can remove that constraint, then we can have a very simple structure where `document` and `task` each have a `content_id` foreign key, and a unique index on it to ensure that no two `document`s have the same `content`.

If we can't remove that constraint, then the answers to your questions are:

1. There is no way to avoid creating those new unique indexes for the foreign keys. Foreign keys must have matching unique indexes.
2. Postgres will not detect that these indexes are redundant, and they will indeed be materialized and take up space.